# Unicode char to wstring

Tags: c++, unicode, char, wstring

I'm trying to send a C# string to a C++ wstring data and vice vera. (by TCP).

I succeeded at sending string data from C#(as Unicode, UTF-16) and got it into at C++ by char array.

But I have no idea how to convert char the array to a wstring.

This is what it looks like when c++ gets "abcd" with utf-16

```
    [0] 97 'a'  char
    [1] 0 '\0'  char
    [2] 98 'b'  char
    [3] 0 '\0'  char
    [4] 99 'c'  char
    [5] 0 '\0'  char
    [6] 100 'd' char
    [7] 0 '\0'  char
```

this is what it looks like when c++ gets "한글" with utf-16

```
    [0] 92 '\\' char
    [1] -43 '?' char
    [2] 0 '\0'  char
    [3] -82 '?' char
```

and this is what it looks like when c++ gets "日本語" with utf-16

```
    [0] -27 '?' char
    [1] 101 'e' char
    [2] 44 ','  char
    [3] 103 'g' char
    [4] -98 '?' char
    [5] -118 '?'char
```

Since UTF-8 doesn't support all Japanese character, I tried to get data via UTF-16 (which C# string basically used).
But I failed to convert these char arrays to wstring by using every way that I have found.

This is what I tried before

```
std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf16<wchar_t>> myconv 
 -> what wchar have to have
        [0] 54620 '한'   wchar_t
        [1] 44544 '글'   wchar_t
 ->What it have after using this 
    [0] 23765 '峕'   wchar_t
    [1] 174 '®' wchar_t
```

/

```
std::wstring wsTmp(s.begin(), s.end()); 

 -> what wchar have to have
            [0] 54620 '한'   wchar_t
            [1] 44544 '글'   wchar_t

->What it have after using this 
        [0] 92 '\\' wchar_t
        [1] 65493 'ￕ'   wchar_t
        [2] 0 '\0'  wchar_t
        [3] 65454 'ﾮ'   wchar_t
```

In both of them, I change char the array to a string and change it to a wstring
and that failed......

Does anyone have any idea how to convert non-English UTF-16 char data to wstring data?

Add : C# side code

```
byte[] sendBuffer = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(Console.ReadLine());
clientSocket.Send(sendBuffer);
```

and it convert '한글' into byte like

```
    [0] 92  byte
    [1] 213 byte
    [2] 0   byte
    [3] 174 byte
```

Comment: You have mismatched types. Use an array of `wchar_t` (or pointer to such) at the C++ side.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: that depends on the protocol being used, and whether the charset for text data can be specified dynamically in the transmitted message data. Using a `char` buffer is perfectly fine as long as it is interpreted correctly when processed.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: No, it doesn't depend on the protocol. You can just look at the data; it's UTF-16. But due to the C# presence here I failed to note that the receiver might not be a *Windows* C++ program (by sheer luck it doesn't invalidate what I wrote, but I would have included that bit if I had just noticed).

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: Just because *some* UTF-16 data is present does not mean the *entire* data is UTF-16. You don't know what the surrounding protocol looks like, so you can't make assumptions about how it is transmitted, received, or processed. The OP only showed one piece of a larger picture.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf : Client : C# Windows or Linux(via mono)                                                  Server : Windows, Visual Studio 2015 RC

Comment: @RemyLebeau: re the noise about possible different encodings, (1) you don't get different encodings, and (2) this data originates with C#.

Comment: @Lee: If it's all Windows then in C++ you can just `reinterpret_cast` the pointer to `char` sequence to pointer to `wchar_t` sequence, and divide length by `sizeof(wchar_t)`, which is 2 in Windows. But note that in Unix-land `wchar_t` might be 4 bytes, and then with UTF-32 encoding, which involves a transcoding operation, not just casting.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: What I sent from C# is `Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(Console.ReadLine());` and byte it converted is same with unicode chart("한글" -> byte[]  '92,213,0,174'). `reinterpret_cast` -> I think it interpret as UTF-8 so it can't interpret something like "当" or "体"(which UTF16 and wstring(it can contain that letter)  can). and I only use windows system.

Comment: @Lee: I just tested with the byte values you state that you receive, and reinterpreting them as Windows wide text, UTF-16 encoding, reproduces your original characters. C++ `reinterpret_cast` does not change the bit patterns, that's much of the point of it and the reason for its name. It just reinterprets the bits according to some specified type.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: than I'm sure that `reinterpret_cast` have "some specified type" which dose not contain "当" and "体"....... I still finding a way to convert char data of "当" and "体" to wstring.......  (anyway I found that "当" and "体"  are in UTF8, but have no idea why char data of them can't be a wstring, while other japanese character can and while C# did all thing well)

Comment: @LEE: `reinterpret_cast` has no type of its own, and does not "contain" characters. It merely tells the **compiler** to interpret one data type as if it were a different data type (like treating a *char* pointer as a `wchar_t*` pointer).  The actual data itself does not change. `reinterpret_cast` is a compile-time type cast, not a run-time type cast.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: I'm more confused. since it works like treating a char pointer as a wchar_t* pointer, than why 当 and 体 can't be a wstring by this method?(I'm sure it's not problem about font or something like that since I can contain these letters to wstring by `wstr = L"体当";`) I can't undestand why ,while other letters(like "明" ,"す") can , they can't.

Comment: You can copy the `reinterpret_cast`ed text to a `wstring`, as is done in @Remy's answer. It's difficult to say what the present problem with letters like "明" ,"す" is about. However, it's *not* about `wstring`.

Answer (score 1):

> I try to send C# string data to C++ wstring data and vice vera. (by TCP)
>
> I succesed to send string data from C#(as Unicode, UTF-16) and get it at C++ by char array.

It would be better, and more portable, to transmit the data using UTF-8 instead of UTF-16.

> But I have no idea how to convert char array to wstring.

On platforms where `wchar_t` is 16bit, such as Windows (which I presume you are on, as you are using C#), you can copy your `char` array content as-is directly into a `std::wstring`, eg:

```
char *buffer = ...;
int buflen = ...;

std::wstring wstr(reinterpret_cast<wchar_t*>(buffer), buflen / sizeof(wchar_t));
```

If you need to support platforms where `wchar_t` is 32bit instead, you can use `std::wstring_convert`:

```
char *buffer = ...;
int buflen = ...;

std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf16<wchar_t>, wchar_t> conv;
std::wstring wstr = conv.from_bytes(std::string(buffer, buflen));
// or:
// std::wstring wstr = conv.from_bytes(buffer, buffer+buflen);
```

Since `wchar_t` is not very portable, consider using `std::u16string`/`char16_t` instead (if you are using a compiler that supports C++11 or later, that is), as they were designed specifically for UTF-16 data.

> Since UTF-8 dosen't support all japanese character

Yes, it does.  Unicode is the actual character set, UTFs are just encodings for representing Unicode codepoints as byte sequences.  **ALL** UTFs (UTF-7, UTF-8, UTF-16, and UTF-32) support the **ENTIRE** Unicode character set, and UTFs are designed to allow for loss-less conversion from one UTF to another.

Comment: Re "`wchar_t` is not very portable", that's less true than that `char` is not very portable. With both types the size can vary. But with `wchar_t` there are only two encodings used in practice, namely UTF-16 and UTF-32, which makes it possible to assume a lot about it, while with `char` there are numeruous encodings used, which makes assumptions a road to disaster. So since `char` objectively is massively less portable than `wchar_t`, if you think one should avoid `wchar_t` then logically there are stronger reasons to also avoid `char`, for text.

Comment: You are confusing data types with encodings. `wchar_t` is a data type, UTF-16/32 are encodings. `wchar_t` is 2 bytes on some platforms, but is 4 bytes on others. `char` is always 1 byte (though not all platforms represent a byte using 8 bits). A `char` buffer can just as easily be used to hold UTF-16 bytes as a 16bit `wchar_t` buffer can. Multi-byte ANSI encodings are numerous, but a `char` buffer can also be used for UTF-8, which is widely supported across platforms. You have to take context into account, and there is a lot of context missing in the OP's question.

Comment: there's still problem. first method -> sent: "本当の正体を明かす" recived: "本?の正?を明かす"(that's why I try to use UTF-16) /-|||-/ second method ->  sent: "本当の正体を明かす" recived: "Ⱨ㼀渰捫㼀鈰๦䬰夰" //-|||-\\ my working environment is 'Windows 10, visual studio 2015 RC for c++', and 'Ubuntu Server for arm 14.04 for C#'

Comment: @RemyLebeau: No I'm not confusing data types with encodings. That's noise.

Comment: @LEE: the fact that you ended up with `?` characters the first time means you are interpreting the bytes as ANSI (not UTF) when converting them to Unicode, and you used an ANSI charset that does not support the characters being sent. You are clearly NOT managing your data correctly. You are also clearly confused about what UTF-8/16 actually are, what `reinterpret_cast` is and how it works, etc. If you want further help, you need to edit your question to show your actual transmit and receive code, because you are clearly doing something wrong with them.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: yup. you're right. I still don't understand what exactly reinterpret_cast do but I found another function which convert recevied data to wstring directly. Thx for your advice~